# Load dependencies after loading view or Template file with AngularJS and $ocLazyLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

I am writing an application with AngularJS. There is a lot of widgets that must be activated using the dependencies scripts. The scripts must run after the contents of the view have been loaded. I have the following state;

```
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard.html",
        templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",            
        data: {pageTitle: 'Admin Dashboard Template'},
        controller: "DashboardController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'DYSCOApp',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before',
                    files: [
                        "assets/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js",
                        "assets/vendor/jqueryui-touch-punch/jqueryui-touch-punch.js",
                        "assets/vendor/jquery-appear/jquery-appear.js",
                        "assets/vendor/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.js",
                        "assets/vendor/jquery.easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js",
                        "assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.js",
                        "assets/vendor/flot.tooltip/flot.tooltip.js",
                        "assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js",
                        "assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js",
                        "assets/vendor/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js",
                        "assets/vendor/jquery-sparkline/jquery-sparkline.js"

                        //ANGULARJS
                        "angular/controllers/DashboardController.js"
                    ] 
                });
            }]
        }
    })
```

I would like to load the JS files after the templateUrl:"views/dashboard.html" file has finished loading.

Comment: did you come up with the solution? I am also facing similar situation.

Comment: A solution that I have come up with is to track the views in .run(